# Action Bar Sherlock giving resource errors

Tags: android, resources, actionbarsherlock

I'm compiling for Android 2.1.  Took a simple example project that was working fine and added the Action Bar Sherlock library and now I'm getting resource errors.  Every line that has a R resource now has an error.  Also, in the console, I'm getting 200+ errors that say something similar to this:

> [CountDownTimerActivity] /Users/kristywelsh/Documents/WorkspacesDec2012/Workspaces/ActionBarSherlock/res/values/abs__themes.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.

There are no errors in my layout file.

I've tried cleaning the project - no luck.  My compiler is targeting 1.6.  Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building it against 1.6? You have to change the build target up to at least 4.0 in order to compile it correctly.

This is because ABS uses different methods for some Android platforms by comparing the Android.os.Build.VERSION. So if you compile it against 1.6 it won't find the Build.Versions and the newer methods.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thanks.